# LinearRegression() with odds y

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have the following train_sizes and accuracies of a knn model:

```
train_sizes = [100, 200, 400, 800, 1600, 3200, 6400, 12800, 25600]
accuracies = [0.702, 0.791, 0.811, 0.866, 0.905, 0.927, 0.939, 0.952, 0.963]
```

I want to compute odds(y)=y/(1-y) with x:

```
# First we traspose the features
X = np.array(train_sizes)[:,np.newaxis]
y = np.array(accuracies)[:,np.newaxis]

#Transform Y, using odds(y)=y/(1-y)
odds_y=y/(1-y)
regression_model = LinearRegression()
regression_model.fit(X, odds_y)
Accuracy_oddsy = regression_model.predict([[60000],[120000],[1000000]])
print('Accuracy for n = 60000, 120000, and 1000000 are:', Accuracy_oddsy)
```

But my accuracies calculations seem to be off because they are way over 1. Can you help me with how to change my code to predict the accuracy using odds(y)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to transform `odds_y` back to `y`:

```
Accuracy_oddsy/(1+Accuracy_oddsy)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.98329271],
       [0.99111439],
       [0.99887043]])
```